# Keep values in <select> for loop after submit

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to retain the values in my select with a for loop option if form is submitted incomplete. It inserts the values into database and functions perfectly fine but I don't want people to have to fill out all the for loop selects again if they submit the form incomplete.

```
if(!empty($_POST['height'])){
    $height = $_POST['height'];
}
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="height">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Height</option>
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=250; $i++)
        {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?>cm</option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

I have my other select functioning perfectly:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['city'])){ 
$city = $_POST['city'];}?>
 <select class=" form-control selectpicker" name="city" value="">
  <optgroup label="Thailand">
   <option disabled selected>Select A City</option>
   <option
    <?php
    if (isset($city) && $city=="Bangkok") echo "selected";?>
    >Bangkok</option>
   <option <?php
    if (isset($city) && $city=="Phuket") echo "selected";?>
    >Phuket</option>
   <option <?php
    if (isset($city) && $city=="Pattaya") echo "selected";?>
    >Pattaya</option>
  </optgroup>
 </select>
```

Essentially I want to achieve the same result as the City select but with the for loop in the Height select.

I have spent the last couple of days researching and trying to implement different codes and strategies to make it work but I still can't get it to function. Any help is greatly appreciated and if there is anymore code or explanation required I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added value in `$height`. But in select, you haven't use it to retain selected value. change your drop-down for height as below-

```
if(!empty($_POST['height'])){
    $height = $_POST['height'];
}
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="height">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Height</option>
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=250; $i++)
        {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if (isset($height) && $height==$i) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $i;?>cm</option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I used the exact same code and it didn't work for me but I copied and pasted your option and it worked perfectly. I guess it must have just been a small typo after all. Either way thank you greatly for your help.